# MOUSE OUT is being called inside MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addeventlistener, movieclip

I added a MOUSE_OVER event listener to my MovieClip, then i added MOUSE_OUT just like this :

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, boxItemMouseOver, false, 0, true);

protected function boxItemMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        trace("mouse over");
        var boxItem:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

        boxItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, boxItemMouseOut, false, 0, true);
        boxItem.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, boxItemMouseOver);       
    }


    protected function boxItemMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        trace("mouse out");
        var boxItem:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

        boxItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, boxItemMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        boxItem.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, boxItemMouseOut);         
    }
```

But whenever i move the mouse inside my MovieClip, the MOUSE_OUT event function is being called, although i still didn't leave the area taken by the MovieClip.

I managed to find out where my Problem is, but still can't fix it, i'm adding to my SWF a Cursor that replaces the icon of the mouse (I hide the mouse), once i add it the problem occurs, here is a simple example.

Code : [Simple Source Code, Couple of classes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/skbsrya8xxma27v/TestOver.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Your fake cursor is probably receiving the mouse events. Set mouseEnabled to false on it

Answer (score 2):

Set `mouseChildren` to false on `boxItem`.

Comment: I did that, still not working, is this a common problem in Flash.

Comment: Not if there are nontransparent pixels in the entire area you want to be rolling over. One thing you can do to try to figure out what is going on is to listen for MOUSE_OVER at the top level and trace out what the target of those events is (whenever your desired object gets a MOUSE_OUT, some other object is getting MOUSE_OVER).

Comment: Amy Blankenship is right on target. MOUSE_OUT will trigger whenever the current target changes from mc to something else which is what happens if inner object inside the mc are allowed to catch mouse events. As said settings mouseChildren to false fixes the issue.

Comment: My MovieClip does contain multiple children, but i'm not sure if it contains transparent pixels, is there a way to find out ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i edited my Question, i also uploaded a simple example and managed to find the source of my problem, still can' fix it though :).

Answer (score 1):

**1..** u have 'trace("mouse over")' in both functions
**2..** first remove mouse over listener, than add mouse out listener
**3..** i don't get, why do u need to declare new variable 'boxItem' when u can             just write e.target.removeEventListener(..)
**4..** it's impossible what u are talking, i caught several unnecessary code in few lines, so there is big chance u are doing somth wrong in your code, show us bigger piece of your code..

p.s. also, try mouseEnabled to false along with mouseChildren to false, but i doubt it will work

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i edited mu Question, i also uploaded a simple example and managed to find the source of my problem still can't fix it though :).

Comment: @ZouhairElamraniAbouElassad , just look over one class, "Items" and I have found your mistake  and solution :) as i mentioned above, it was impossible what u were talking, mouseChildren = false; works just fine, but u use it in a wrong way, dont use it with boxItem variable, but with a source variables, i saw u have 'Zad_Block_04' and 'Zad_Gate_02' variables and i assume they are source,so, assign mouseChildren = false; to them,not to the boxItem

Comment: and as i also mentioned above, there is no need of 'boxItem' variable, just write: e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, boxItemMouseOver);
 e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, boxItemMouseOut, false, 0, true);
 e.target.setChildIndex(e.target.getChildByName("active"), (boxItem.numChildren-1));

Comment: and it's a good practice that first check child,before retrieve it, sorry for my english but i think u guess what i write, i mea n this:   if(e.target.getChildByName("active") != null){
  e.target.setChildIndex(e.target.getChildByName("active"), (boxItem.numChildren-1));
 }

Comment: i just saw above @Amy Blankenship made u to make a mistake :D "Set mouseChildren to false on boxItem." this is a big big mistake, this will never work, always assign this kind of properties to the source variable

Comment: Hi buddy thanks for the explanation :), i did all you said, i added mouseChildren to the sources, i also removed boxitem with e.target, i didn't work i tried e.currentTarget but it didn't work as well, but i've discovered the source of my problem, i'm using a custom cursor that follows the mouse, when i remove it everything works fine, so it must be   it, but i still don't know how the use it with MOUSE_OVER.

Comment: now here is a questions: how are u declaring,how are using,what u are doing with custom cursor :D ok,here is my advice, remove custom cursor, make your program work, when u will be ready and have enough knowledge, than add custom cursor again, there is a saying in my country "straight your legs to the point, where blanket ends" or blanket is enough, i dont know english well and i dont know how well i translated this saying, but hope u get the point

Comment: Thanks for the feedback dude, actually i'm making it work without the custom cursor, the cursor just follows the mouse, i edited my Question and added the source code it's simple you can downloaded to check it yourself :), as for the saying i think i get the meaning that's very kind of you and by the way i find your English quite good, i'm not a native speaker as well, so we're both trying ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for `ROLL_OUT` instead. `MOUSE_OUT` is dispatched when cursor left any of the nested chidlren of you `MovieClip`.

Comment: But i want to change the state of my MovieClip once i'm Over it.

Comment: OK, so use `ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT`

Comment: this answer cannot possibly fix the issue. Voted down.